# Add together 2 dataframes in R without losing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes in R (df1, df2).

```
A C D
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

df2 as

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

How can I merge these 2 dataframes to produce the following output?

```
A B C D
2 1 2 1
4 2 4 2
```

Columns are sorted and column values are added. Both DFs have same number of rows. Thank you in advance.
Code to create DF:

```
df1 <- data.frame("A" = 1:2, "C" = 1:2, "D" = 1:2)
df2 <- data.frame("A" = 1:2, "B" = 1:2, "C" = 1:2)
```

Comment: I think the asker is trying to add the data frames together, not join them.

Comment: @divibisan yes. that is where my difficulty is :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nm1 = names(df1)
nm2 = names(df2)
nm = intersect(nm1, nm2)

if (length(nm) == 0){                  # if no column names in common
    cbind(df1, df2)
} else {                               # if column names in common
    cbind(df1[!nm1 %in% nm2],          # columns only in df1
          df1[nm] + df2[nm],           # add columns common to both
          df2[!nm2 %in% nm1])          # columns only in df2
}
#  D A C B
#1 1 2 2 1
#2 2 4 4 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df2, df1) %>%
  map(rownames_to_column) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  rowname     A     B     C     D
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 1           2     1     2     1
2 2           4     2     4     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. this is a good solution but it outputs just 1 row in the end which is the addition of all values in that column. Let me add more rows to the DFs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

By using `left_join()` from `dplyr` you won't lose the column

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- tibble(a = 1:10,
               b = 1:10,
               c = 1:10)

dat2 <- tibble(c = 1:10,
               d = 1:10, 
               e = 1:10)

left_join(dat1, dat2, by = "c")
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>        a     b     c     d     e
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1     1     1     1     1
#>  2     2     2     2     2     2
#>  3     3     3     3     3     3
#>  4     4     4     4     4     4
#>  5     5     5     5     5     5
#>  6     6     6     6     6     6
#>  7     7     7     7     7     7
#>  8     8     8     8     8     8
#>  9     9     9     9     9     9
#> 10    10    10    10    10    10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response. There are multiple intersecting columns in df1 and df2. Plus I do not think this will add the values inside the columns.

Comment: for multiple you can just specify `by = c("c" = "c", "a" = "a")` so on and so forth where the first "c" is your lhs data and 2nd "c" is from the rhs data. For the adding, then I don't think you've worded your question well and edit it so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
allnames <- sort(unique(c(names(df1), names(df2))))

df3 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df1), ncol = length(allnames)))
names(df3) <- allnames

df3[,allnames %in% names(df1)] <- df3[,allnames %in% names(df1)] + df1
df3[,allnames %in% names(df2)] <- df3[,allnames %in% names(df2)] + df2

df3
  A B C D
1 2 1 2 1
2 4 2 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun base R method with `Reduce`.

```
Reduce(cbind,
       list(Reduce("+", list(df1[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))],
                             df2[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))])), # sum results
                             df1[setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))], # in df1, not df2
                             df2[setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))])) # in df2, not df1
```

This returns

```
  A C D B
1 2 2 1 1
2 4 4 2 2
```

This assumes that both df1 and df2 have columns that are not present in the other. If this is not true, you'd have to adjust the list.

Note also that you could replace `Reduce` with `do.call` in both places and you'd get the same result.